# How to call multiple variables in function and select statement using snowflake procedure

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to write query to pass multiple variables in multiple sessions in snowflake procedure?

Source tables: `location`, `locationdetails`, `emp`, `dept` and `location function`.

I want to pass a variable value to the function and variable value call into another select statement

```
create table location (locationid integer ,locationname varchar)
create table locationdetails (locationid integer ,distince varchar,country varchar)
insert into  location (locationid,locationname) values (1,'del')
insert into  location (locationid,locationname) values (2,'che')
insert into  locationdetails (locationid,distince,country) values (2,'50 km','india')
insert into  locationdetails (locationid,distince,country) values (1,'40 km','india')
insert into  location (locationid,locationname) values (2,'che')
create temp table dept as select 10 deptid;
create temp table emp as select 'a' a, 'b' b, 10 deptno;

create or replace function location(locationid integer)
returns table (locationid integer,locationname varchar)
as
$$
select * from location where locationid in (locationid)
$$;


call emp_locresult()
select * from locationdetails
create or replace procedure emp_locresult()
returns table ()
language sql
as
$$
declare
 empresult integer; 
 locationresult integer;
begin
 select deptid into :empresult from DEPT where deptid=10;
 let res resultset := (select * from emp where deptno = :empresult);

select  locationid into :locationresult from location where locationid=1;
 let res1 resultset := (select * from locationdetails where locationid = :locationresult);
 
 let res2 resultset : =(select * from table(location(:locationresult) ))
return table(res1);
return table(res2);
return table(res);

end;
$$;
```

This query results in an error:

> Syntax error: unexpected ':'. (line 24)
> call emp_locresult()

Please tell me how to write this query to call multiple variables into multiple sessions in stored procedure in snowflake

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to generate a dynamic SQL to call your table function with a parameter:

```
create or replace procedure emp_locresult()
returns table ()
language sql
as
$$
declare
 empresult integer; 
 locationresult integer;
begin
 select deptid into :empresult from DEPT where deptid=10;
 let res resultset := (select * from emp where deptno = :empresult);

 select  locationid into :locationresult from location where locationid=1;
 let res1 resultset := (select * from locationdetails where locationid = :locationresult);
 
 let res2 resultset := (execute immediate 'select * from table(location( ' || :locationresult || ') )' );
 -- return table(res1);
 -- return table(res2);
 return table(res);
end;
$$;
```

You can't return 3 different tables. The first return will end the procedure and return the value.

Comment: after call procedure I can see only 1st res values only that is emp result and not able to see locationdetails  and funcation result. how will see those all 3 statements results .can u help on it

Comment: @jaiparkumar I have already answered this question. Please read the last line. Your queries return different columns, if they were returning the same number of columns, you can combine them with UNION but I don't know how it would help.